# Navbar Collapse not working properly in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

It's my mvc partial view:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.RouteLink("მთავარი", "AdminControlUsers", null, new { @class = "navbar-brand", @style="padding-left:100px; padding-right:100px"})//this line
            </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    @if (ViewBag.NavBarActive == "მომხმარებლები")
                    {
                        <li class="active">@Html.RouteLink("მომხმარებლები", "AdminControlUsers")</li>
                        <li>@Html.RouteLink("Stored Procedures", "ControlStoredProcedures", new { page = 1 })</li>
                        <li>@Html.RouteLink("გაშვებული Stored Procedure-ები", "Admin_User_Results_List")</li>
                    }
                    @if (ViewBag.NavBarActive == "Stored Procedures")
                    {
                        <li>@Html.RouteLink("მომხმარებლები", "AdminControlUsers")</li>
                        <li class="active">@Html.RouteLink("Stored Procedures", "ControlStoredProcedures", new { page = 1 })</li>
                        <li>@Html.RouteLink("გაშვებული Stored Procedure-ები", "Admin_User_Results_List")</li>
                    }
                    @if (ViewBag.NavBarActive == "User_Admin Results List")
                    {
                        <li>@Html.RouteLink("მომხმარებლები", "AdminControlUsers")</li>
                        <li>@Html.RouteLink("Stored Procedures", "ControlStoredProcedures", new { page = 1 })</li>
                        <li class="active">@Html.RouteLink("გაშვებული Stored Procedure-ები", "Admin_User_Results_List")</li>
                    }
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    li><a href='@Url.Action("LogOut", "Administrator")'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> გამოსვლა @Session["Admin"].ToString()</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

When I resize my browser my navbar screenshots:
[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

When I delete one line of it:

```
@Html.RouteLink("მთავარი", "AdminControlUsers", null, new { @class = "navbar-brand", @style="padding-left:100px; padding-right:100px"})
```

if i delete  @style="padding-left:100px; padding-right:100px" it works properly :/. Please help

Comment: What you wish to achieve exactly? third picture collapse button activates as expected, on second one your content is overflowing being pushed up, you don't want the navbar to collpase? Or you would like it to collapse sooner than when the overflow happens?

Comment: Yes @Syden. I want collapse and don't get navbar as it is in second and third picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content is overflowing sooner than collapse `button`, you would need to set the navbar collapse button to display earlier.

You can do so via CSS, set this last on your stylesheet (adjust `min-width` and `max-width` to your desire):

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none !important;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse.in {
        display: block !important;
    }
    .navbar-header .collapse, .navbar-toggle {
        display:block !important;
    }
    .navbar-header {
        float:none;
    }
}
```

[Test it on this resizable external Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Syden/5mfvj9v2/5/)

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Syden, but when i resize browser now button is displayed,but other options too

Comment: I'm sorry I don't follow, the options are what you shared I don't know what other options maybe or not. Whatever you want to be inside the collapse `button` place it inside of `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">option</div>`. Whatever is left outside of that will be visible.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <nav id="menu" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 2</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>        
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I explore that this line:@Html.RouteLink("მთავარი", "AdminControlUsers", null, new { @class = "navbar-brand", @style="padding-left:100px; padding-right:100px"})

Comment: And this in it: @style="padding-left:100px; padding-right:100px"

Comment: And in this code you add in answer is as my if there isn\'t @style element

Comment: I don't use MVC Web ever. Sry about that. You can use javascript to add class and CSS to style for this.